# BitNami WordPress installation messes up ApacheFriends XAMPP Control Panel

Tags: mysql, windows, apache, windows-7, bitnami

This is not a duplicate of existing posts on this topic but rather a specific case.

I installed the XAMPP 1.8.1-0, started apache and mysql from the xampp control panel,
and then tried installing WordPress via the XAMPP BitNami library WordPress module.
Towards the end of the installation however I got this error in XAMPP Control Panel:

16:27:05  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
16:27:05  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
16:27:05  [Apache]  Problem detected!
16:27:05  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 5572!
16:27:05  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
16:27:05  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
16:27:05  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

and when I ckecked with netstat from the XAMPP control panel, I could see that
netstat shows httpd.exe running on ports 80 and 44, in fact I can load the WordPress
web pages from the server.

Has anyone experienced this? I am thinking that since I moved the old XAMPP installation
to C:\xampp.old the httpd.exe file located in such directory is being launched
automatically (somehow windows found it and started it despite the folder rename)?
I regret that netstat does not show you the full path of the directory from
which the httpd.exe was launched, which would make things much clearer.

This will probably fix it, but I still won't have understood what had happened,
especially since, oddly, once I rebooted apache would start from the control panel
but not mysql.

I will now uninstall both of them, reboot, and reinstall only one XAMPP.

If someone encountered thiese problems and can explain them, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody is answering this question I will answer it on my own using the limited information I can provide. Here is what I did:

1. I uninstalled all instances of BitNami XAMPP applications.
2. I uninstalled all versions of XAMPP.
3. I enabled the hidden Administrator account on Windows 7
   via the following command: “net user administrator /active:yes”
4. Reinstalled in C:\xampp to avoid UAC issues.
5. When logged in as a regular user, right click on xampp and select the
   menu entry saying to always run it as administrator.
6. Secure the XAMPP installation as per `http://localhost/xampp/` -> Security.
7. Install any BitNami applications AFTER setting up XAMPP security in step 7.

Once finished I did not have any problems except for Mercury Mail Transfer Agent,
and I posted a question related to it here:

https://superuser.com/questions/657615/xampp-mercury-mail-transfer-agent-not-working

although I haven't received any answers to it as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this. I'm sorry that you found the issue installing the Bitnami for XAMPP modules. However these modules don't modify your XAMPP installation. They only try to restart the servers. From the error you pasted, it seems that another proccess was running in port 80. It could be related to your all XAMPP installation but unfortunately with the information you provided it is not possible to know.

If you find this issue in the future please feel free to check with us in the bitnami forums.

(Disclaimer: I'm part of the Bitnami team)

Comment: Same issue here. Bitnami wordpress windows installer works fine as it packages apache inside, but bitnami wordpress module runs fine and messes up XAMPP control panel Apache.